# IBAction Triggered By Time

Tags: cocoa-touch, time, ios8, ibaction

What I want is an IBAction command in Xcode that is automatically triggered every second. It would perform similar to a button, triggering a set of commands.

Thanks for your time,
jjj

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTimer`, which is the Foundation framework class that does exactly what you've asked for.